# can't create token

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp, tokens

I copy and pasted the coin code into the ethereum wallet contracts section - gave it a name and:

- initial supply: 10000
- decimal places: 2
- symbol: Kk

When the contract gets picked up it has no name (a blank space), and 0's for all the numbers and no symbol...none of what I put in got transfered over. Are the values I am using wrong?

Comment: for me you question is not quite clear would you please formulate it

Comment: Without the source code of your contract is almost imposible to know what went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It was a few things, or one of these: I changed the symbol to 3 letters, all uppercase and made sure it wasn't already taken. In my code, I had written "contract KarmaKoin {" instead of leaving it as "contract MyToken {". You name it as one of the options that pops up so you don't need to worry about that in the code.